# Is it Possible Show Dynamic Iframe content using HTML Viewer Visual in Power BI?

Tags: html, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have tried various tricks but nothing seems to be working :(

Steps:

1. Driver Data coming from SQL Server as Direct Query with IFrame Content (This makes rest call to some web service) as Column
2. Using `HTML viewer visual` to show `IFrame` content

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104381214?tab=Overview

By default I just want to show Google.com on HTML but when they select any row from the list it pass HTML content for the selection to the HTML viewer. Is it possible!!!

I have tried `selectedValue, IsCrossfiltered, HasOneValue` all sort of tricks to see if it allow me to switch to default value when there is no selection and actual value when you click any row to crossfilter.

> Without Selection

[image]

> With Selection

[image]

Need HTML content except Google.com while do selection!!!

Answer (score 0):

found this while searching how to embed HTML code into my report.. Not really an answer though.

"A final note: Not all web pages can be rendered in an iframe. Some websites such as Google and Amazon do not allow their content to be hosted on another site via iframes. Keep this in mind when using this trick"

https://powerpivotpro.com/2018/11/dynamically-embedding-web-pages-in-power-bi/